# How to exclude certain words in sentence. regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of sentences, like:

```
 let arr = [
      "I like an apples",
      "I worked yesterday all day",
      "Anna went on holiday to Madrit",
      "They went to the party to LA"
       ]
```

and I really want to exclude a sentence, which has a LA word. Im not sure it is ok using a regex. 
I've tried to use :

```
\b([a-z0-9])\b(!CLT)
```

to have all senteces where is not LA, but it doesnt worked.
Any idea is this the best solution to to this?

Comment: You might want to have a second look at a regular expression tutorial.

Comment: _"The LAPD caught the thief"_ - Would this be also a "match"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am really out of knowledge of regex. That's why this so complicated :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply using `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
let arr = [
    "I like an apples",
    "I worked yesterday all day",
    "Anna went on holiday to Madrit",
    "They went to the party to LA"
]
const res = arr.filter(x => !x.includes('LA'));
console.log(res)
```

If you only want to check for words only then you can `split(' ')` and then `filter()`

```js
let arr = [
    "I like an apples",
    "I worked yesterday all day",
    "Anna went on holiday to Madrit",
    "They went to the party to LA",
    "LAST Four words"
]
const res = arr.filter(x => !x.split(' ').includes('LA'));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: What if any sentence has LA as a substring not a word? Say ```IT LASTS FOR HOUR```

Comment: Now it's working. But I think ```regex``` is much faster than this. BTW this is great.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wanting something like this-

```js
let arr = [
  "I like an apples",
  "I worked yesterday all day",
  "Anna went on holiday to Madrit",
  "They went to the party to LA",
  "Hello world LA Demo"
];

let modifiedArr = arr.filter(v => {
    let regex = /\bLA\b/i;

    if (!regex.test(v)) {
     return true;
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(modifiedArr);
```